# Working with unicode in cython

Tags: python, c++, unicode, utf-8, cython

I have a script, written in cython, which gets an array of C++ strings as input, feeds them to pymorphy2 analyzer and then processes the result. During build this script is being translated to C++ source code with command:

`cython ${SCRIPT_FILENAME} -o "morph-analyzer.cpp" -2`

In this script there is a definition of function, which performs communication with pymorphy2:

```
cdef analyzeToken(const UnicodeString tok, vector[pair[UnicodeString, vector[shared_ptr[AnalysisResult]]]] &analysis_results):
    cdef vector[shared_ptr[AnalysisResult]] res_for_tok    
    cdef shared_ptr[AnalysisResult] analysis_res

    cdef string utf8_str
    tok.toUTF8String(utf8_str)
    morph_results = morph.parse((utf8_str.c_str()).decode('UTF-8'))

    cdef unsigned propMask
    for morph_result in morph_results:
        analysis_res = make_shared[AnalysisResult]()
        if morph_result.score > 0.1:
            deref(analysis_res).normalForm = UnicodeString(morph_result.normal_form.encode('UTF-8'))
            propMask = 0 
            if morph_result.tag.POS is not None:
                deref(analysis_res).partOfSpeech = UnicodeString(morph_result.tag.POS.encode('UTF-8'))
            if 'Name' in morph_result.tag:
                propMask |= FIRST_NAME
            if 'Patr' in morph_result.tag:
                propMask |= PATR
            if 'Surn' in morph_result.tag:
                propMask |= SECOND_NAME
            if 'Init' in morph_result.tag:
                propMask |= INIT
            if 'Geox' in morph_result.tag:
                propMask |= GEOX
            deref(analysis_res).nameCharMask = propMask
        else:
            deref(analysis_res).normalForm = tok
        res_for_tok.push_back(analysis_res)
     analysis_results.push_back(pair[UnicodeString, vector[shared_ptr[AnalysisResult]]](tok, res_for_tok))
```

Input string, which needs to be analyzed, passed into this function as `UnicodeString` (from [icu4c library](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/)) object named `tok`. First, I'm extracting std::string object in utf-8 format

```
cdef string utf8_str
tok.toUTF8String(utf8_str)
```

After that, I need to get python unicode string in order to pass it to `pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer.parse()` method. According to [cython documentation](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/strings.html), C-string are treated by python as byte strings, so I'm calling `bytes.decode('UTF-8')` and then passing the result to pymorphy2.
When processing results, I'm converting unicode strings from pymorphy2 to bytes objects by calling `encode('UTF-8')`.
It works fine in Linux when using Python 2.7.13 and Cython 0.25.2. But in Windows with the same versions of Python and Cython I get very strange results: input text is being corrupted and analysis failes. There is a sample debug output:

`Current token: Original word: нижес▒едующем, normal form: ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒␰▒`

Correct version is:

`Current token: Original word: нижеследующем, normal form: нижеследующий`

I have not yet been able to figure out, why the same code works fine under Linux and failes under Windows. Could you please suggest any reason for this?

Comment: I've just dabbled with strings in `cython`, but my sense that `C` strings aren't very useful.  In Py3 unicode's the default string type; in Py2 you can create unicode strings with the `u` prefix.  Can you go directly from Python strings to the C++ `Unicode`?

Comment: You mean if I can construct `UnicodeString` object from python string? I believe there is no way to do so, python unicode string, which we get from pymorphy2, should be encoded first.

Comment: I believe the conversion `morph_results = morph.parse((utf8_str.c_str()).decode('UTF-8'))` is mangling the string. The intention there is to parse a C string into a Python utf-8 string, correct? If so, what is being decoded needs to be a python bytes string. The C string implementation varies via platform, which is why you see different behaviour. In all, convert to python bytes first, then decode to a Python UTF-8 string. See [Cython working with strings](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/strings.html?highlight=character%20conversion#accepting-strings-from-python-code) _ustring